# How to mutually exclude two program sections

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have the following Java concurrency problem:

1. There are two functions, **f1** and **f2**, which can be executed by any thread in arbitrary order
2. More than one thread is allowed to execute **f1** at the same time
3. More than one thread is allowed to execute **f2** at the same time
4. No thread is allowed to execute **f1** if **f2** is being executed by at least one thread, and vice versa for **f2**

Now the straightforward (suboptimal) implementation would be:

```
class AccessedByManyThreads {
  void doActionWithF1() {
    foo();
    synchronized (this) {
      f1();
    }
    bar();
  }
  void doActionWithF2() {
    baz();
    synchronized (this) {
      f2();
    }
    faz();
  }
}
```

This implementation satisfies requirement 4., however it doesn't avail of relaxations allowed requirement 2. and 3. Effectively I'd need here something like ReadWriteLock where not only Read lock can be shared but the Write lock as well.

So my questions:

1. Are there any Java concurrency lib primitives I could use to satisfy requirements 2. and 3.?
2. If not, what an idea for the implementation would be?

Comment: What do you need it for?  If you just implement your rules with locking, then the result is unstable -- as long as there are threads doing F1, nobody is going to do F2, and vice versa.  You will probably need a strategy for switching between F1 and F2 that will need to be informed by your actual use case

Comment: @MattTimmermans 
"as long as there are threads doing F1, nobody is going to do F2" - that's fine in my use case. What I have is bursty invocations of f1, then after some time of f2. They however can be smeared over time line, but still retain bursty nature. Multiple threads invoking f1() (or f2()) without locking is fine due to concurrency guarantees of f1 (f2) implementations, however I cannot allow f2 being executed when f1 is due to correctness issues.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if there is any Java concurrency library that would help in this use case. However, you can simulate something similar to semaphore variables to achieve this:

```
class AccessedByManyThreads {
    private int threadsAccessingF1;
    private int threadsAccessingF2;

    public AccessedByManyThreads() {
        this.threadsAccessingF1 = 0;
        this.threadsAccessingF2 = 0;
    }

    public void doActionWithF1() {
        synchronized(this) {
            if(threadsAccessingF2 > 0) {
                return;    
                // some function(s) are accessing f2, so return without calling f1()
            }
            else {
                threadsAccessingF1++;
            }
        }
        f1();
        synchronized(this) {
            threadsAccessingF1--;
        }
    }

    public void doActionWithF2() {
        synchronized(this) {
            if(threadsAccessingF1 > 0) {
                return;    
                // some function(s) are accessing f1, so return without calling f2()
            }
            else {
                threadsAccessingF2++;
            }
        }
        f2();
        synchronized(this) {
            threadsAccessingF2--;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you reply. I've implemented something similar in the end, though using Object's wait() and notifyAll(). I just cannot shake off the feeling that this use case should be possible with Java concurrency lib primitives and that this is reimplementation of a wheel -/

Answer (score 0):

1. I don't think there's a standard library class that will help you out of the box.
2. A solution :

The situation is comparable to a crossroads, where f1 and f2 are the two intersecting roads. A traffic light would allow either traffic from f1 to pass or from f2, but never both at the same time. I've come across such a problem in the past and then built this synchronizer class :

```
public class TrafficLight<T> {

    private ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock(true);
    private Condition switched = lock.newCondition();
    private int registered;
    private int maxBeforeYield = 20;
    private T state;

    public void acquire(T t) throws InterruptedException {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            while ((state != null && !state.equals(t)) || maxBeforeYield == 0) {
                switched.await();
            }
            if (state == null) {
                state = t;
            }
            registered++;
            maxBeforeYield--;
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        lock.lock();
        try {
            registered--;
            if (registered == 0) {
                state = null;
                maxBeforeYield = 20;
                switched.signalAll();
            }
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

You create a trafficLight, and make methods that try to call f1() acquire state "F1", and methods that try to call f2() acquire state "F2" (you can use other state objects obviously).

The class, as presented, forces a switch of state, as soon as 20 or more threads are waiting for a different state. This is basically equivalent to setting both directions to a red light, and then the other direction to green as soon as the crossroads is cleared.